# Clonezilla can't restore disk

Tags: linux, clonezilla

Recently I moved all of the clonezilla backup file from one serve to another. I am now trying to restore an image to a flash drive and it's giving me an error.

The error message was "target_parts is not assigned in function task_restoreparts"

I've tried Googling for a solution with the error to no avail.

Comment: It sounds like the restore image is not complete.

Comment: Clonezilla uses partimg to do the bulk of the backup work. I would be willing to bet that the error you are seeing pertains more specifically to partimg rather than clonezilla as a whole.

Comment: Yes, Ramhound is right. Somehow when I copied the images over to another server, it didn't copied correctly. I'm glad I have a backup of my backups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many problems seem to occur with some SSD drives, especially when it comes to partitioning, I suggest you try to restore on a standard magnetic drive before looking further.

*Clonezilla* does not only use *partimage* to backup/restore. It chooses either automatically or by asking you, which backend will be called to do the job.

*Partimage* is a very good tool from my experience, but I've had a problem once, running it from a live distro, which name is *INSERT* (sorry, don't remember the version). All created images (either ext3 or NTFS) were unusable, and no error message was given during backup.

Please ensure the reported size of the destination partition matches the reported size of the backup, including unused space. Clonezilla also saves alot of meta information about the whole drive on which backed up partitions are located. Did you try to restore manually, one by one, using the backend program that created the backup ?

Answer (score 0):

That occurred to me when I mistakenly specified **/dev/sdc** instead of simply **sdc** as the destination.

Indeed, the program could be more verbose by providing the original error code and message (such as “Could not open /dev/dev/sdc — file does not exist”) rather than just printing a cryptic line of text that looks more like an internal bug tracker and not an indication of bad input.